# Crash (not caught by dispatcherunhandledexception nor app.unhandledexception)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a c# wpf app which crashes randomly and my error handling does not catch anything. Here is my error log:

```
Version=1
EventType=APPCRASH
EventTime=129271636864718697
ReportType=2
Consent=1
UploadTime=129271636865498698
ReportIdentifier=a87ddcc9-afd1-11df-89ed-002643aeed97
IntegratorReportIdentifier=a87ddcc8-afd1-11df-89ed-002643aeed97
WOW64=1
Response.BucketId=2005953524
Response.BucketTable=1
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Application Name
Sig[0].Value=CUE.exe
Sig[1].Name=Application Version
Sig[1].Value=1.0.0.0
Sig[2].Name=Application Timestamp
Sig[2].Value=4c7409bf
Sig[3].Name=Fault Module Name
Sig[3].Value=StackHash_4450
Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Version
Sig[4].Value=0.0.0.0
Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
Sig[5].Value=00000000
Sig[6].Name=Exception Code
Sig[6].Value=00000000
Sig[7].Name=Exception Offset
Sig[7].Value=00000000
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=6.1.7600.2.0.0.768.3
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=2057
DynamicSig[22].Name=Additional Information 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=4450
DynamicSig[23].Name=Additional Information 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=4450a15b06af705108d230c618ed9564
DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=0dd3
DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=0dd368cae20a1e97a2d2ebda8404c0c4
UI[2]=C:\Users\Wouter\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\V8E6QLVG.22B\JKBQO2ZQ.CRK\cue...tion_50f30a00538d7296_0000.0007_f13e8c4e74f23d5d\CUE.exe
UI[3]=CUE has stopped working
UI[4]=Windows can check online for a solution to the problem.
UI[5]=Check online for a solution and close the program
UI[6]=Check online for a solution later and close the program
UI[7]=Close the program
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Users\Wouter\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\V8E6QLVG.22B\JKBQO2ZQ.CRK\cue...tion_50f30a00538d7296_0000.0007_f13e8c4e74f23d5d\CUE.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\syswow64\verifier.dll
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\vrfcore.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\vfbasics.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\vfcompat.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNEL32.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\syswow64\SHELL32.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR100_CLR0400.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\4ff1f12a08d455f195ba996fe77497c6\mscorlib.ni.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\nlssorting.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\Windows\system32\RpcRtRemote.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\Windows\system32\dfshim.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\Windows\syswow64\urlmon.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\Windows\syswow64\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPT32.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\Windows\syswow64\MSASN1.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\Windows\syswow64\iertutil.dll
LoadedModule[39]=C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\161c6f80ad93b0505054d244f1c6243c\System.ni.dll
LoadedModule[42]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\WindowsBase\f1f3a74eb37b27b7d05b8ffa941f8473\WindowsBase.ni.dll
LoadedModule[43]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\PresentationCore\7a1eeb425f9318f432afead4b2da965a\PresentationCore.ni.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\PresentationFramewo#\8357ade60159c25ee88db0aab8686e6d\PresentationFramework.ni.dll
LoadedModule[45]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xaml\d85a3d6ed5bb77f5603e098cccf60bfa\System.Xaml.ni.dll
LoadedModule[46]=C:\Windows\system32\dwrite.dll
LoadedModule[47]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\wpfgfx_v0400.dll
LoadedModule[48]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\PresentationNative_v0400.dll
LoadedModule[49]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
LoadedModule[50]=C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
LoadedModule[51]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Deployment\0778748cd9700240f093adfc5dfc5750\System.Deployment.ni.dll
LoadedModule[52]=C:\Users\Wouter\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\V8E6QLVG.22B\JKBQO2ZQ.CRK\cue...tion_50f30a00538d7296_0000.0007_f13e8c4e74f23d5d\irrKlang.NET4.dll
LoadedModule[53]=C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR100.dll
LoadedModule[54]=C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
LoadedModule[55]=C:\Users\Wouter\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\V8E6QLVG.22B\JKBQO2ZQ.CRK\cue...tion_50f30a00538d7296_0000.0007_f13e8c4e74f23d5d\ikpflac.dll
LoadedModule[56]=C:\Users\Wouter\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\V8E6QLVG.22B\JKBQO2ZQ.CRK\cue...tion_50f30a00538d7296_0000.0007_f13e8c4e74f23d5d\ikpmp3.dll
LoadedModule[57]=C:\Windows\syswow64\CLBCatQ.DLL
LoadedModule[58]=C:\Windows\System32\dsound.dll
LoadedModule[59]=C:\Windows\System32\POWRPROF.dll
LoadedModule[60]=C:\Windows\syswow64\SETUPAPI.dll
LoadedModule[61]=C:\Windows\syswow64\CFGMGR32.dll
LoadedModule[62]=C:\Windows\syswow64\DEVOBJ.dll
LoadedModule[63]=C:\Windows\System32\MMDevApi.dll
LoadedModule[64]=C:\Windows\System32\PROPSYS.dll
LoadedModule[65]=C:\Windows\system32\AUDIOSES.DLL
LoadedModule[66]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Core\85693dfd9ba4905b0fd947fdb51446d5\System.Core.ni.dll
LoadedModule[67]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Microsoft.Expressio#\d9faddcc5491ab760c5c74272d31eb2b\Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.ni.dll
LoadedModule[68]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Inte#\03056aa579134f3de0cfc1983b172bbd\System.Windows.Interactivity.ni.dll
LoadedModule[69]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xml\2d7c29ad77c15abfa6a8fe6d24840a91\System.Xml.ni.dll
LoadedModule[70]=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll
LoadedModule[71]=C:\Windows\system32\mscms.dll
LoadedModule[72]=C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
LoadedModule[73]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Configuration\ac2cd19f2159d48684e17cbdecfaa3b7\System.Configuration.ni.dll
LoadedModule[74]=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsCodecsExt.dll
LoadedModule[75]=C:\Windows\system32\icm32.dll
LoadedModule[76]=C:\Windows\system32\d3d9.dll
LoadedModule[77]=C:\Windows\system32\d3d8thk.dll
LoadedModule[78]=C:\Windows\system32\atiumdag.dll
LoadedModule[79]=C:\Windows\system32\atiumdva.dll
LoadedModule[80]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\PresentationFramewo#\b4e58d1a3e0ee75b6b107585c92c68e8\PresentationFramework.Aero.ni.dll
LoadedModule[81]=C:\Windows\system32\shfolder.dll
LoadedModule[82]=C:\Windows\system32\WtsApi32.dll
LoadedModule[83]=C:\Windows\system32\WINSTA.dll
LoadedModule[84]=C:\Windows\system32\msctfui.dll
LoadedModule[85]=C:\Windows\system32\sxs.dll
LoadedModule[86]=C:\Windows\system32\explorerframe.dll
LoadedModule[87]=C:\Windows\system32\DUser.dll
LoadedModule[88]=C:\Windows\system32\DUI70.dll
State[0].Key=Transport.DoneStage1
State[0].Value=1
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
ConsentKey=APPCRASH
AppName=CUE
AppPath=C:\Users\Wouter\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\V8E6QLVG.22B\JKBQO2ZQ.CRK\cue...tion_50f30a00538d7296_0000.0007_f13e8c4e74f23d5d\CUE.exe
```

To make sure here is my error handling code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;

namespace CUE
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {

            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}\n", e.Exception.Message);
            stringBuilder.AppendFormat(
                    "Exception handled on main UI thread {0}.", e.Dispatcher.Thread.ManagedThreadId);

            // attempt to save data
            var result = MessageBox.Show(
                            "Application must exit:\n\n" + stringBuilder.ToString() + "\n\nSave before exit?",
                            "app",
                            MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
                            MessageBoxImage.Error);
            if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.InnerException.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.InnerException.Message.ToString());

            }

            // Return exit code
            this.Shutdown(-1);

            // Prevent default unhandled exception processing
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
        }

        void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            Exception ex = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Uncaught Thread Exception", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I look for solutions for these kinds of errors where there is no information on failing components or stacktraces or exceptions..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously the crash is not occurring in a managed thread, you covered that.  You'd better ditch those audio codecs that you are using.  Or get help from the [vendor forum](http://www.ambiera.com/forum.php?f=1).

Comment: Allright so the problem lies in the external component? Or can it be that I use external code in my app which triggers exceptions in the external code? I mean then I'll post this to the ambiera forum but how should he know where to look then, there is no lead in this error...

Comment: I can't look over your shoulder from here.  Maybe you ought to work on the smallest possible repro...